# Powershell invoke command under different user on the same machine

Tags: powershell, credentials

I need to run a copy-item under a different user, because the user that runs the script doesn't have access to the destination folder. Essentially I'm trying for this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { param($DropLocation, $remoteDropLocationOnTest) Copy-Item $DropLocation $remoteDropLocationOnTest -recurse } -auth CredSSP -cred $cred -ArgumentList $DropLocation $remoteDropLocationOnTest
```

but the problem is this seems to be meant to run scripts on different machines. when I do this, I get an error saying that I need to specify a target computer. Is there a way I can get around this? I'm using powershell 2.0

Comment: Have you tried using localhost or dot (".") as the ComputerName?

Answer (score -1):

I see a serious syntax error in your code. The `-ArgumentList` parameter accepts an array of objects, but you are specifying one argument, and another one **separated by an space** and not by a **comma**. You must correct this error first.

Comment: The code was was supposed to provide a demonstration of what I need to do. You can think of it as pseudocode.